# encrypt data using aes-128-ecb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

> I have To encrypt data using aes-128-ecb in nodejs my code is
>
> I am using Crypto to encrypt data

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const secret = '1000060000000000';

const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', secret);

const ciphertext = cipher.update('9', 'utf8', 'base64')+cipher.final('base64');

console.log("Cipher text is: " + ciphertext);
```

the output should be `EtgITaHs6lEvEHBipj08Kg==`
but the output is coming as `nNzqejauQBnfiDqznGhZ0Q==`

Comment: Use `crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', secret, null)` instead of the _deprecated_ [`createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options). The latter uses a KDF, which is obviously not intended for your case.

Comment: **Security warning:** Please don't use ECB mode. Use at least a mode of operation with a random/unpredictable IV so your encryption is semantically secure. Then you should use a mode of operation that also supports authentication, like AES-GCM. Authentication is necessary if you want to detect (malicious) modifications to the ciphertext. This is useful because many modes of operation are malleable.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the use of [crypto.createCipher](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options), it doesn't use the key directly, but rather a digest.

To quote the documentation:

> The implementation of crypto.createCipher() derives keys using the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt.

If we use [cipher.createCipheriv](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) on the other hand, we can specify the key directly and it will give us the expected output.

Here's an example:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function encrypt(plainText, key, outputEncoding = "base64") {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, null);
    return Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plainText), cipher.final()]).toString(outputEncoding);
}

function decrypt(cipherText, key, outputEncoding = "utf8") {
    const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, null);
    return Buffer.concat([cipher.update(cipherText), cipher.final()]).toString(outputEncoding);
}

const key = "1000060000000000";
const plainText = "9";
const encrypted = encrypt(plainText, key, "base64");
console.log("Encrypted string (base64):", encrypted);
const decrypted = decrypt(Buffer.from(encrypted, "base64"), key, "utf8")
console.log("Decrypted string:", decrypted);
```

The output will be

```
EtgITaHs6lEvEHBipj08Kg==
```

Comment: Totally worked, this should be marked as the solution

Answer (score 0):

It is late but will help others
You can pass any Algorithm i.e. aes-128-cbc , aes-128-ecb

Create a new file and name it as `aes-service.js` in service folder or anywhere in Node.js application

aes-service.js

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    
    const cryptkey = 'C51GH00SE8499727';
    const iv =  'BDA30EGDH1578F81';
    
    
    async function encrypt(text){
        try {
            var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc',cryptkey,iv);
            var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64');  //base64 , hex
            crypted += cipher.final('base64');
            return crypted;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('encrypt error',err);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    async function decrypt(encryptdata){
        //Check all Algorithms
        console.log(crypto.getCiphers()); // ['aes-128-cbc', 'aes-128-ccm', ...]
    
        try {
            let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc',cryptkey,iv)
            decipher.setAutoPadding(false)
            let decoded  = decipher.update(encryptdata,'base64','utf8') //base64 , hex
            decoded  += decipher.final('utf8')
            return decoded
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('decrypt error',err)
            return null
        }
    }
    
    const AesService = {
        encrypt:encrypt,
        decrypt:decrypt,
    }
    module.exports = AesService
```

Node.js contorller i.e abc.controller.js
//Get aes encrypted data from node.js request

```
    const AesService  = require("./services/aes-service")
    
    exports.getAesEncryptedDatafromReq= async (req, res) => {
       
        try{
            let decryptData = ''
            try{
                const buffers = [];
                for await (const chunk of req) {
                    buffers.push(chunk);
                }
                const dataBuffer = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();
                const jsonParsedData = JSON.parse(dataBuffer)
                decryptData = jsonParsedData.data
            }catch(err){}
    
           
          
            let decryptedData = await AesService.decrypt(decryptData)
            console.log('decrypted data',decryptedData)
    
            let sendbackdata = {
                "status": 0,
                "anotehr_key":[
                    { "dec":"0", "asc":"1"}
                ]
            }
            sendbackdata = JSON.stringify(sendbackdata)
            let encryptedData = await AesService.encrypt(sendbackdata)
            
              //Check if encrypted performed well
             // let decryptedDataAgain = await AesService.decrypt(encryptedData)
            //console.log('decryptedDataAgain ',decryptedDataAgain)
    
    
            return res.status(201).send({"data":encryptedData})
    
        }catch(err){
            return res.status(500)
        }
    }
```

Add route

```
 router.post("/get/aes/encrypted/data/from/req", controller.getAesEncryptedDatafromReq)
```